# jqGrid - assign class to nav buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jqgrid

I'm using jquery jqGrid plugin. I use `navButtonAdd` method for adding navigation buttons to my grid. Here is an example for adding a navigation button:

```
$("#grid").navButtonAdd("#pager", {
      title: "title",
      caption: "caption",
      buttonicon: "fa fa-search",
      id: "test",
      position: "last",
 });
```

This produce a `<td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all" id="test">` inside `ui-pg-table`. Now I want to add class to that `<td>`. In fact I want to have `<td class="ui-pg-button ui-corner-all my-desired-class" id="test">` after grid initialization. But, based on [jqGrid Custom Button documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons), `navButtonAdd` does not have `class` parameter. One solution is to manually assign class to `<td>`s via jquery, But this is not a good solution. How can I do that? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

There are no option of `navButtonAdd` which will allow you set class to new button (to `<td>` element). So you can either set the class by `id`: `$("#test").addClass("my-desired-class");`. If you wanted to set the class `my-desired-class` only to set your custom CSS settings you can probably set the same CSS settings by usage id selector `#test {...}` instead of the class selector `.my-desired-class {...}`.